# Why does referencing "src/main/resources" work after compilation, during testing?

Tags: java, maven

How is it that I can get a resource at runtime through a `new File("src/main/resources/test.txt")` reference in my source code? As far as I know, Maven puts these files within the target/classes and target/test-classes directories/classpath for testing and runtime use. What is happening behind the scenes?

Thanks!

Comment: Presumably, you're launching your application with a current working directory that includes that `src`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've built this specific code through Jenkins. It is hosted on a Git server. You're saying that the running application is getting this test.txt from my project's directory?

Comment: I'm saying that you're running your `java` process from a directory that contains `src/main/resources/test.txt`.